# Node js pdf upload

Tags: node.js

Hello how can I upload a pdf file in nodejs i try this sharp package but it doesn't work actually

**await sharp(req.files.cover[0].buffer)
.resize(2000, 1333)
.toFormat("jpeg")
.jpeg({ quality: 90 })
.toFile(`public/img/catalogues/${req.body.cover}`);**

Comment: sharp is not for uploading files

Comment: i want to upload pdf

Answer (score 1):

sharp is used to resize or compress your files , try using multer . multer is used to deal with all kind of files.

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work since that the file uploaded is pdf

await sharp(req.files.pdf.buffer)
    .toFile(`public/img/catalogues/${req.body.cover}`);